# Problem with Unity's Pyshics.RaycastAll layer parameter

Tags: unity-game-engine

This raycast always returns an empty array if I use the layer parameter, but if I don't use it everything works properly.
I wanted to make a separeted layer for my enemies(trigger colliders) in order to optimize the process.

```
private RaycastHit[] GetRaycastHits(int layer = 0)
{
    return Physics.RaycastAll(partToRotate.position, partToRotate.forward, ShootRangeDistance, layer);
}
```

Its very weird that even if a pass LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default") it doesn't work.
I made sure that my enemies are on default layer for now and I already tried to pass the parameter that allow the cast to hit triggers.

Comment: I have this problem too. But, if I use a layer mask (as default number) in a regular raycast, then everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Layer mask wrong!

See [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)

> The Physics.Raycast function takes a bitmask, where each bit determines if a layer will be ignored or not. If all bits in the layerMask are on, we will collide against all colliders. **If the layerMask = 0, we will never find any collisions with the ray.**

**For further understanding of bitmasks**

A bit mask basically works like the following:

Each (in this case) layer is represented by one enabled (1) or disabled (0) "bit".

Remember that one `int` in the binary backend is basically just 4 bytes => 32 bits => 32 available layers in Unity.

Let's say for now there are only 8 layers as an example.

So the bitmask looks like e.g.

```
0000 0001
```

Now I'll add the indices on top of it so you understand what I'm talking about

```
//indices 7654 3210
          0000 0001
```

this means the layer at index `0` is enabled, anything else is disabled. This would have the `int` value `1` (= `2^0`)

A second example

```
// indices 7654 3210
           0000 1010
```

this would mean the layers at index `1` and `3` are enabled, the `int` value would be `10`. **Why? Because it equals

```
0*2^7 + 0*2^6 + 0*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0

= 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 0

= 10
```

In order to write it easier you would usually use [bitshift operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-) like e.g.

```
var layers = 1<<3 | 1<<1;
// In bits   1000   10
```

which would result in the last mask example.

---

So the `Default` layer actually would be

```
int defaultLayer = 1<<0;
```

**which does not equal `0` but rather `1`!**

---

In order to not have to do the Layer calculations or hardcode it via string you should rather use a  [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) field like

```
public LayerMask raycastLayers;
```

in your component, configure it via the Inspector and later pass it in like

```
// This is possible because LayerMask has an implicit conversion from int to LayerMask
//                                                       |
//                                                       v
private RaycastHit[] GetRaycastHits(LayerMask hitLayers = 1<<0)
{
    return Physics.RaycastAll(partToRotate.position, partToRotate.forward, ShootRangeDistance, hitLayers.value);
}
```

and

```
var hits = GetRaycastHits(raycastLayers);
```

Comment: really appreciate that you took your time to give me a really detailed answer. I am sorry that the answer was right on my face, I read the layer section of unity docs but somehow that last part about selective cast got by me without noticing.
It is really interesting that we use binary for this layer configuration and it makes all the sense, though I'm still curious about why the LayerMask.GetLayerByName returned the index number of the layers instead of the integer representing the binary. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `layerMask` is for layers you wish to ignore.

Try inverting it ('bitwise' inversion):

```
return Physics.RaycastAll(partToRotate.position, partToRotate.forward, ShootRangeDistance, ~layer);
```

Comment: No, it is not ...the phrasing in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) is just a bit misleading ..  otherwise it would ignore all the default raycast layers by default ;)