# How do I get all overlapped Collider2D on any layer in LayerMask array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to choose all elements in the array

```
public LayerMask[] ground;
```

I have a problem "Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 1", with:

```
a = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(bottom.position, radius, ground[0, ground.Length]);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Debugging questions need to include enough information 1. to explain the desired behavior and 2. to reproduce the problem. See [mre] for more information.  From what you've shared so far, it seems like `ground` isn't a type that makes sense to double index with `[0][1]`.

Comment: Regarding the code after the edit, it seems like `ground` is not a two dimensional array or some other type which supports the `[]` operator with two indices. It will make it easier to help you if you share in your post 1. what type `ground` is. and 2. what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I need to choose all elements in the array

Comment: Okay, really appreciate

Comment: What do you expect `ground[0, ground.Length]` to represent?

Comment: Why use an array in the first place? In a `LayerMask` field you can select multiple layers via the Inspector anyway ...

Comment: [Maybe this helps to understand how a LayerMask works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423626/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

Use the logical OR `|` operator to combine the masks then do one OverlapCircle with that combined mask, and then you can call the override of `OverlapCircle` that will give you multiple results. You'll have to create a `ContactFilter2D` to do so:

```
// Initialize the results list once and keep it around to avoid unnecessary 
// garbage collection
List<Collider2D> overlapResults;

void Awake()
{
    overlapResults = new List<Collider2D>(); 
}

// ... in the method in question...

int allMask = 0; 
foreach (LayerMask lm in ground) 
{ 
    allMask = allMask | lm.value; 
} 
ContactFilter2D filter = new ContactFilter2D();
filter.SetLayerMask(allMask);

Physics2D.OverlapCircle(bottom.position, radius, filter, overlapResults);
foreach (Collider2D overlapResult in overlapResults) 
{
    // do stuff with overlapResult
}
```

Comment: Why use an array in the first place? In a `LayerMask` field you can select multiple layers via the Inspector anyway ...

Comment: @derHugo No particular reason, that's just the type used in the question.Someone else could find this post looking for help handling a list of LayerMask collected in an editor script, and this answer could help them.

Comment: @Brian Did you find a solution to this problem? If my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).